# Connecting tableViews in interface builder to a NON-outlet variable

Tags: ios, uitableview, interface, interface-builder, tableview

I'm trying to figure out how to connect a tableview I've defined in my NIB file to a variable in the header file, the only thing is, the variable is defined as:

@property (strong, nonatomic) UITableView *bimbitTableView;

and NOT

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *recevtPlacesTableView;

for some reason it's only allowing me to connect to outlets. Also I the reason I am connecting to a variable is I want to reload the data multiple times programmatically.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Just add the keyword `IBOutlet` to your first declared property.

It is simply a hint to Interface Builder that you want to be able to connect an outlet to it, and there is no other reason to not put it there.  It actually is a "variable" (technically a declared property) no different than the one without the keyword.

Comment: I see, I'm seeing some legacy code in which IBOutlet is *not* there,yet it's still connected via the NIB. are you saying this is errant and/or bad programming practice? Thainks.

Comment: @UbaDuba, I don't see how that's possible. As far as I know you can't connect a property to a something in a nib file without the IBOutlet keyword.

Comment: @UbaDuba, It might appear that you can connect a property without the IBOutlet keyword, because after you make the connection (with IBOutlet present), you can delete IBOutlet from your property's declaration, and the connection will remain. It could be that's what you've seen. But as Inafziger said, there's no reason not to have that keyword there.

Comment: yea aight, thanks rdelmar, that's probably what happened. thanks for the reply.